# How to transform daily to weekly data given public holidays on Friday?

Tags: r

I am puzzled at a point where I want to transform daily data into weekly where there are many events at which the markets are closed on Fridays. I have to transform the daily data of USDINR from daily to weekly and Monthly where there are 18 public holidays in one year and 360 public holidays for 20 years. Will there any faster method to deal with this problem? Suppose, I have data to which I can create binary variable to filter the daily into weekly data.

```
for(i in 1:length(df01$day)){
        
if(df01$day[i] == 'Friday'){
        
df01$count[i] = 1
        
} else df01$count[i] = 0
        
if(seq(df01$count[i] == 0)>4){
        
df01$week['Thursday'] = 1
        
} else df01$week[i] = 0
        
}
```

where `df01$week[i]` return value 0.

So the days of public holiday on Friday, how can I capture one day earlier day i.e. Thursday to assign weekly close of the market?
I further tried following code , however, returns value zero.

```
for(i in 1:length(df01$day)){
        
  if(df01$day[i] == 'Friday'){
        
    df01$count[i] = 1
        
  } else df01$count[i] = 0
        
}
        
        
for(i in 1:length(df01$day)){
        
  if(df01$count[i] == 1 & df01$count[i]+5 == 0){
        
    df01$week[i]+4 = 1
        
  } else df01$week[i] = 0
        
}
```

I simply want to assign 1 for Thursday in case of public holiday on Friday, where Friday will be missing from real time historical data. Therefore '0' between two consecutive '1' will be greater than 4. Hope the audience have got my point. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "transform the daily data [...] to weekly data" ?

Comment: What do you want to do with `if (seq(df01$count[i] == 0)>4)`?

Comment: Hi Julien, I thanks for commenting on my error. I have explain my modified code in above querry. I just want to figure out and assign 1 to earlier working day (it may me the case that there would be two consecutive public holidays) in case of missing Friday. Hope you will reply the erliest. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your code, the format is not good